# Supervisor program not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, supervisord

I create a test here:

```
vi /etc/supervisor/conf.d/test.conf
```

It looks like this:

```
[program:sentry-test]
command= echo "hello there"
```

I then run the command with the output:

```
supervisorctl reread
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.6.egg/supervisor/options.py:286: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
No config updates to processes
```

Then I try:

```
supervisorctl start sentry-test
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.6.egg/supervisor/options.py:286: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
sentry-test: ERROR (no such process)
```

I have not idea why not one of my programs will work?

Server:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config file have a extra space:

`command=echo "hello there"`

Remove the space after `command=` and it should work.

Comment: Thats defenetly not it, it works when calling it manualy. But same thing even without the space.